# Populate does not work in mongoose create

Tags: node.js, mongoose

User schema looks something like this

```
  addressId: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'address' }],
  mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Address model

```
mongoose.model('address', postalAddressSchema);
```

I am trying to do this:

```
const createdUser = await mongoose.models.user.create(user);
return { success: true, user: createdUser.populate('addressId') };
```

I am trying to populate address in user creation. It returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to find, populate and exec after creating the user. Here is a working example

```
const theMongoose = await mongoose.connect(mongoServerUri);
const accountModel = theMongoose.model(
    'Account',
    new Schema({
        _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String
    })
);
const activityModel = theMongoose.model(
    'Activity',
    new Schema({
        account: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account' },
        date: Date,
        desc: String
    })
);
const account = await accountModel.create({ name: "Test User", _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromTime(new Date().getTime()/1000) });
await activityModel.create({ date: new Date(), desc: "test", account: account.id });

// find, populate, & exec
const res = await activityModel.find({ desc: "test" }).populate("account").exec()
console.log(res);
```

And the output is

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62da50ec77c026e2aad5577b"),
    account: {
      _id: new ObjectId("62da50ea0000000000000000"),
      name: 'Test User',
      __v: 0
    },
    date: 2022-07-22T07:25:32.119Z,
    desc: 'test',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```